# Verificar se valor existe em array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array

Possuo um array que é da seguinte maneira

```
[
  {
    "Param": 1,
    "Valor": 68
  },
  {
    "Param" 1,
    "Valor": 79  
  },
  {
    "Param": 2,
    "Valor": 165
  }
]
```

Gostaria de saber como verificar se o numero (no `Valor`) existe no array, caso exista, eu removo, caso não exista, eu adiciono.
Estou fazendo isso ao marcar um `checkbox`, se eu marco, eu adiciono no array, se eu desmarco, eu retiro, não estou usando jQuery.

Meu código para adicionar

```
this.checkOne.push({
          "Param": check,
          "Valor": id
        })
```

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira para retirar

```
this.checkOne.map(val => {
          if(val.Valor.indexOf(id) != -1){
            alert('Tem')
          }else{
            alert('nao tem')
          }
        })
```

Comment: Se é um `checkbox` que irá controlar, não basta verificar se ele está selecionado ou não? Pois se ele estava selecionado, o elemento deve existir, se não estava, você inserirá o valor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você chegou perto, só que o `map`não é o método mais adequado, porque foi feito para transformar uma array em outra. Para excluir você vai precisar do índice do elemento que será removido, então é melhor usar [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
let checkOne = [
  {
    "Param": 1,
    "Valor": 68
  },
  {
    "Param": 1,
    "Valor": 79  
  },
  {
    "Param": 2,
    "Valor": 165
  }
];

function adicionaOuRemove(id) {
  let index = checkOne.findIndex(val => val.Valor == id);
  if(index < 0) {
      checkOne.push({Param: 0, Valor: id});
  } else {
      checkOne.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

adicionaOuRemove(165); // existe
console.log(checkOne)

adicionaOuRemove(99);  // não existe
console.log(checkOne)
```

Comment: Eu não consegui entender o codigo, poderia explicar? e tambem não funcionou aqui, ele adiciona, mas nunca cai para remover, sempre dá como se não existisse o valor, mesmo depois de eu ter adicionado

Comment: Tinha um erro no meu código. Corrigi e ampliei o exemplo pra você ver funcionando. Qual parte do código você não entendeu?

Comment: Agora funcionou, valeu amigo :D

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma bem simples de conseguir o resultado seria com uso de um comando de loop for. de forma bem simples você consegue iterar sobre todos os elementos do seu array de objetos e verificar com if se existe o valor na propriedade desejada. deixo um exemplo bem simples da solução.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "Param": 1,
    "Valor": 68
  },
  {
    "Param" :1,
    "Valor": 79  
  },
  {
    "Param": 2,
    "Valor": 165
  }
]

function addOuRemoverObj(valor){



var encontrou = false;

for(var index = 0, total =arr.length; index < total; index++){

var obj = arr[index];

if(obj.Valor == valor){
    arr.splice(index,1);
    encontrou = true;
 break;
}

}


if(encontrou == false)
{
   arr.push({"Param":3, "Valor": valor});
   
}


console.log(arr);

}
//remove
addOuRemoverObj(79);

//adiciona
addOuRemoverObj(333);
```